# Firebase HTML TAG are not active in page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I have a WYSIWYG editor in my angular project and my users can save them modified posts in my Firebase database (With HTML TAG).

But, when I want to display them, I have something like this :

In HTML :

[image]

In DOM :

[image]

In Firebase :

[image]

How can I active them ?

Thank you all !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some search, I found a solution for those who have this problem : Use ng-bind-html.

Like this :

```
<div ng-bind-html="products.reassurance_text"></div>
```

And it's activate the HTML in page. ;)

Hope it's help someone !